# Is it possible to share an analysis file programmatically?

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

Can I share an analysis file with another user by using the build in notification system as well as sending an email to the user both done programmatically (e.g. using the JavaScript API or IronPython or C# APIs) and not using the UI interface of Spotfire WebPlayer? I have looked online as well as the official Spotfire documentation but I was unable to find if that is possible.

**To better illustrate the problem, consider the following scenario**:
We have 2 websites. The 1st website has a map and a query builder, the user builds the query and then goes to a second website by pressing on a link. The 2nd website has 2 pages. The 1st page is the landing page. The landing page then retrieves all of the library items (using web services) from the user's folder (each user has one). The user can click on any of those links and gets taken to the second page that has Spotfire loaded in it which loads the selected library item/analysis file.

Back on the landing page, we are trying to add a "sharing" functionality which will allow the "current" user to select a few library items (i.e. links) and then type in a user's email (for example) and press share). Can that be achieved programmatically as we do not have Spotfire in that 1st page?

**Note**: the user gets automatically signed in (using a custom auth logic) when switching from site 1 to site 2.

Comment: can you describe with a little more detail the flow you're looking to implement here? it sounds like Automation Services might be the way to go but I'd like to better understand your desired process before giving a definitive answer :)

Comment: Hi, again @niko. I have added more detail. You are right, it was not that clear. Apologies for the late response.